# how to write a algorithm given the condition using python

Tags: python

Approximate the value of n for the formula `(1-1/n)**n` for which the difference between the value of `n` in the formula and `1/e` is less than 0.0001.

How can we do using while and for loop in python .

I tried using `while` with the following code

```
from math import exp
value = 1/exp(1) # e being the exponential
n = 1;

while check < 0.0001:
    n=n+1
    formula = (1-1/n)^n
    check = value - formula
    if check <0.0001:
        print(n)
```

but since check is not defined before `while` the program doesn't run.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: `(1-1/n)^n` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: use `while True` and break if condition on check is met;

Comment: Do you mean: `(1-1/n)**n`?

Comment: Yes ** is the correct one thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define check at the beginning, and replace `^` with `**`, as the latter one is the correct way to write power in python

```
import math
value = 1/math.exp(1) # e being the exponential
n = 1
check=1

while check > 0.0001:
    n=n+1
    formula = (1-1/n)**n
    check = value - formula

print(n)
```

By the way, `^` is the bitwise xor operator in python. You can look here for further description:
http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_XOR.html